# Angular 2+ npm start issue

Tags: angular

I have downloaded an application, and as per the read me i have just run npm install, now while running npm start getting issue shown in snap-shot.

[image]

[image: different application on npm install]

Comment: have u installed angular CLI?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik they'd see a different error if `ng` wasn't in their path

Comment: Do you have the *right version* of the Angular CLI? *Is* there a project definition file in the directory where you're running that command?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik earlier I had installed angular CLI, but please let me know how can I cross check it.

Comment: This tutorial is obsolete (current version of angular is 7, current version of the CLI is 7.1.4.) and badly configured. Read from the official Angular documentation, or from an up-to-date book.

Comment: I guess you mean this one: https://github.com/zakiziko/SpringBoot-angular4-Mongodb-Tutorial

Comment: @piyushvijayvargiya you need to reset up your project according to me uninstall `cli` and reinstall angular `cli` and ` npm i`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yeah true i am working on this only.

Comment: @FatemeFazli, can you please look help on this.

Comment: now i have downloaded one more application, and facing the same issue [screen shot attached.]

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that the directory where you are running this command has the package.json file 
also give it a try by ng serve --host= your ip

ng serve without host will by default launch the application at localhost :4200